# Script to get all "stopped" services with startup type "automatic" -- Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

So if a service has a startup type of "Automatic" or "Manual" but is currently stopped I would like to run a command to see those issues.

In powershell and CMD I am able to see one OR the other, but there is no easy way I can find to filter the data to what I need.

I am basically looking to make script for trouble shooting services. It is going to be able to determine if there are any services that should be started (based on their startup type) but are not running (stopped or suspended).

The issue I am running into is that powershell or CMD do not allow for in depth filter or piping of results. Does any one have a way to help me figure this out?

How can I go about solving this issue?

Comment: As an alternative approach, you can use `sc` to find information on services and control them using text filtering.

Answer (score 3):

By looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304821/get-startup-type-of-windows-service-using-powershell) you could come up with this for old versions of PowerShell:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service | Select-Object Name,State,StartMode | Where-Object {$_.State -ne "Running" -and $_.StartMode -eq "Auto"}
```

With newer Versions (at least 5 maybe 3/4) you could also use (which was suggested by JC2k8):

```
Get-Service | Select-Object -Property Name,Status,StartType | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Stopped" -and $_.StartType -eq "Automatic"}
```

In older versions of PowerShell the `Get-Service` cmdlet doesn't offer a member that has the `StartType`.

PowerShell supports a lot of filtering and piping. :)

Comment: According to the same link you should probably use something like the following statement (if you're running Powershell version 5):

`Get-Service | Select-Object -Property Name,Status,StartType | where-object {$_.Status -eq "Stopped" -and $_.StartType -eq "Automatic"}`

Comment: You're correct but the above method also works on older versions of PowerShell. PowerShell 5.0 would be the default with Windows 10. I'm not sure how `Get-Service` behaves on PowerShell 3.0/4.0 at least on PowerShell 2.0 (Windows 7) `Get-Service` doesn't have `StartType` as a member.

Comment: This is actually not correct, you are getting everything back not just "Automatic"; you are getting triggered start and delayed start potentially .

Comment: Yes and no. The mentioned APIs don't expose that kind of information adn it wasn't actually part of the original requirement. Those services are still set to an automatic startup type. The filter ensures just automatic is being collected. If you need that kind of information you need to dig deeper into those services or e.g. parse the output of `sc.exe`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256942/how-to-check-the-start-type-of-a-windows-service-is-auto-or-auto-delayed-usi).

Answer (score 2):

```
(get-service|?{ $_.Status -eq "Stopped" -and $_.StartType -eq "Automatic"})|
select DisplayName, StartType, Status
```

Comment: What's the idea behind the parenthesis? Your script only checks if it's stopped while the initial question also wanted to catch the status suspended. If we assume there could be other states filtering for `!= Running´ could be better.

Comment: I get piping confusion when piping to 2nd or 3rd level, so I make it a habit to parenthesize wherever possible. But in this case it serves no purpose. on the '!=Running' part, how about -ne 'Running' ?

Comment: With `!= Running` I meant `-ne 'Running'` just wanted to save those extra characters! Thanks for explaining your reasoning for the parenthesis. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this if suits your issue. The below code helps you start all stopped services related to Sophos AV that should be running because they have Automatic start type.

```
# Start specific automatic start services not running
$service = "*sophos*"
$server = "<server_name>"
$stoppedServices = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $server | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $service -and $_.StartMode -eq 'Auto' -and $_.State -ne "Running"}).Name
foreach ($stoppedService in $stoppedServices) {
  Write-Host -NoNewline "Starting Server/Service: "; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $server"/"$stoppedService
  Get-Service -ComputerName $server -Name $stoppedService | Start-Service
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Stopped"} | where starttype -match automatic
```